# Есть ли среда для разработки мобильного приложения на PHP?

Tags: php, mobile-development

Написала мессенджер на PHP, который лежит локальном сервере Денвер. Как можно конвертировать его в мобильное приложение? Существуют ли такие программы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить свой проэкт на хостинг
далее скачиваем:

1. jdk и jre
2. android sdk
3. android studio от jetbrains
4. запускаем и создаем шаблон приложения
5. добавляем element webview и указываем разрешения в манифесте для интернета
6. в webview забиваем ссылку на опубликованное приложение
7. компилируем и запускаем

Ну или используем phonegap для этих же целей логика та же инструмент другой просто http://phonegap.com/blog/tag/android/

Answer (score -1):

Есть от  самого Zend, смотри тут http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio раздел Mobile development

Comment: smarter development это умная среда. И ответ должен быть развёрнут